# Match array Filters in an Array not providing desired result

Tags: mongodb, array-filter

I am new to MongoDB, learning from its documentation, stuck at the *array Filters* topic.

This Query simply update the defined element of array **arrayOp**  in all document using array Filters

```
db.inventory.updateMany(
{},
{ $set : {"arrayOp.$[element]" : 200} },
{ arrayFilters : [{ "element" : 0}] })
```

On executing above query

> { "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 8, "modifiedCount" : 0 }

**Document**

[image]

Comment: `"modifiedCount" : 0` makes sense since there are no values equal to `0` in `arrayOp`. Do you expect something else here ?

Comment: Yeah, thanks I misunderstood the concept

Answer (score 0):

Hey if anyone faces the problem regarding the concept, how it works

Cite this  [**documentation**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)